# How are answers accepted after the OP's account is deleted?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, deleted-accounts

If a user asks a questions and gets a proper answer and the user becomes inactive forever or deletes his account without accepting the answer, then does any other person has a privilege to accept the answer other than OP? If no, then how to deal with such questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No one<sup>1</sup> can accept an answer except the OP of the question.

In general, it doesn't matter since an acceptance only means that the answer [*helps **OP** the best*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally.

However, Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for public. It strives to help many people, not only the OP. This is indicated by the voting, which is more important in long-term.

The voting is also used by the system to indicate if a question is ["unanswered"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) or not: accepted/*upvoted* answers.

---

<sup>1. Except Stack Exchange employees directly accessing and modifying the database, but that's never recommended.</sup>

Comment: But since this site is in beta stage. It is necessary for increasing the accepted answers. If the users delete and  answers get un-ccepted. Then the % of answered questions go down.

Comment: @hanugm The "% of answered questions" includes "questions with upvoted answers". This is what SE deemed as "answered".

Comment: @hanugm We consider accepting answers completely optional. There's no pressure on anyone to accept an answer and we don't judge whether a site should graduate based on accept rate, so don't worry about it too much.